# Admin encoding problem

Tags: admin, encoding

My breadcrumbs plugin is taking blog name as starting point:

blog name > category title > post title

The problem is if I set the blog name in cyrillic characters it is desappearing as soon as "save" button is pressed. So in admin it looks like an empty field. On the site the question characters are shown where blog name should be. Check here [k-gayduk.ru](http://k-gayduk.ru/portfolio.html)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the appropriate character set in your `wp-config.php` file.  utf8 is a safe bet.

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```